# How Does npm --save Decide Which Version and SemVer Options?

Tags: npm, dependencies, package

If I type the following into my computer

```
$ echo '{}' > package.json
$ npm install pug --save
```

and then look at my `package.json`, I'll see that `npm` added a dependency for me.

```
#File: package.json
{
    "dependencies": {
        "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.1"
    }
}
```

Sweet!  However -- how does `npm` decide to grab version `2.0.0-rc.1`?  And how does `npm` decide to use the `^` SemVer version modifier?

As a user of `npm` can I configure or tell it to use a different SemVer modifier and/or download a different version? (both a specific version and/or something like "latest stable")

As an `npm` package maintainer, can I specify that `npm`'s default behavior should be something other than *"grab the latest version and slap a `^` on there"*?

Comment: https://github.com/npm/npm/blob/d46015256941ddfff1463338e3e2f8f77624a1ff/lib/install/save.js#L143

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#save-prefix

Comment: Useful docs, +1 both, thank you.  However, (unless I'm missing something) they don't clearly address the different contexts in my questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

npm takes the latest tag publicly available and `^` is the default, you can use `save-prefix` to change it locally.

To a get specific version use `@version` after package name i.e. `npm install pug@0.1.0`.
Something like composer's `minimum-stability` doesn't exist in npm world.

As a maintainer, you can't do anything, except keeping SemVer and writeing good code :)

But at all `package.json` is just a JSON, you can simply modify them, without using any CLI commands and define whatever you need.