# How to configure save-prefix for own npm registries

Tags: npm, verdaccio

I have [save-prefix](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#save-prefix) configured as per default to add '^' as version prefix. This works well for (unscoped and scoped) packages which I install from npmjs. However for packages which come from my own registry ([verdaccio](https://github.com/verdaccio/verdaccio)) it does not append the prefix:

```
> npm install --save @my-scope/my-package
> cat package.json
...
"dependencies": {
  "@my-scope/my-package": "0.0.42",
}
```

From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920874/how-does-npm-save-decide-which-version-and-semver-options) I learned, that the save-prefix is a local thing and is not influenced by registry or package.json.

Do I have to locally configure the save-prefix for my registry? If so: how/where?

Any other ideas on why the '^' is not prepended for packages from my own registry?

My .npmrc looks like this:

```
@oblamatik:registry=https://npm.dev.***********.ch
//npm.dev.oblamatik.ch/:_password="***************"
//npm.dev.oblamatik.ch/:username=ci
//npm.dev.oblamatik.ch/:email=ci@***********.ch
//npm.dev.oblamatik.ch/:always-auth=true
```

Comment: Does it work for a non-`0.x` package from your own registry?

Comment: I had to create one as we are still in early development. But, yes, for non-0.x packages this works. Any information on why that is the case?

Comment: I think you might want to raise a bug with npm. The prefix behaviour is different for 0.x and that's either wrong or if intentional the docs should mention this.

Comment: Posted it here, so everyone feel free to take part in that discussion: https://npm.community/t/save-prefix-is-not-prepended-for-major-version-0/4618

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently npm treats versions of the form 0.0.x as not being a valid SemVer (https://npm.community/t/save-prefix-is-not-prepended-for-major-version-0/4618).

I expressed my disagreement in that bug report, but for now, the answer is:

*Do not use versions below 0.1.0 with npm.*

Even though they are valid SemVer as of [SemVer specification 2.0.0](https://semver.org/), npm treats them differently. For reference this is the code excerpt posted by the npm developer on their bug report:

```
if (isRegistry(requested)) {
    var version = child.package.version
    var rangeDescriptor = ''
    if (semver.valid(version, true) &&
        semver.gte(version, '0.1.0', true) &&
        !npm.config.get('save-exact')) {
      rangeDescriptor = npm.config.get('save-prefix')
    }
    return rangeDescriptor + version
}
```